# How to send a text message or a link from controller to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have got a submit button for a form, this controller actionresult method gets called when the button is pressed. Depending on the return of the `_shortUrlProcessor.CreateShortURL` method. I want to either display a message in red or a create a link under the mentioned submit button. What is the proper way of handling this in MVC? (see comments in code for more clarification as well)

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ShortenURL(ShortURLModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(_shortUrlProcessor.CreateShortURL(model.originalURL, model.shortURL))
            {
                ViewBag.ShortenURLSuccess(model.shortURL); //< ---- send as a localhost:port/model.shortURL link
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.ShortenURLSuccess("Could not create link"); //<----send as a text label (which would be shown in something like a <div/>)
            }
        }          
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Seems like all of this should be handled in the view, and you can use your viewbag variables to return the shortURL, and/or a Boolean on whether or not the state is valid. If using the viewbag is your preferred method, that is. Is there a reason to keep it out of the view and content has to stay in the controller?

Comment: @BenMatthews There is no reason the controller could not simply send the shorturl and a boolean as you say. How would it be coded in the view? where if boolean == true display a link with shorturl. If boolean == false, display a message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this in the view is the way to go, and here is an example using the viewbag approach:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ShortenURL(ShortURLModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(_shortUrlProcessor.CreateShortURL(model.originalURL, model.shortURL))
        {
            ViewBag.ShortenURLSuccess=true;
            ViewBag.ShortenURL=model.shortURL;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ShortenURLSuccess=false;
        }
    }          
    return View();
}
```

And then in the view:

```
@if (ViewBag.ShortenURLSuccess)
{
    <a href="localhost:port/@ViewBag.ShortenURL">Go here</a>
}
else
{
    <div class="error">Could not create link</div>
}
```

If you need more information for the url or the message, you can put those in viewbag variables as well.

it is worth noting that a more popular way to do this is with model binding, but this approach works fine for what it is. You can use the submitted model and move away from the viewbag to be a bit more efficient.